# How many $2 \times 2$ matrices are there with entries from the set ${\{0,1,2,...,i}\}$ in which there are no zeros rows and no zero columns?

Tags: combinatorics

How many $2 \times 2$ matrices are there with entries from the set ${\{0,1,2,...,i}\}$ in which there are no zeros rows and no zero columns?

attempt:
Suppose we have a matrix $ \begin{pmatrix} 
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{pmatrix}$. Then we don't want $ \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$ or $ \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\
c & d 
\end{pmatrix}$ or $ \begin{pmatrix} 
a & b \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$.

Similarly for the columns.
Then we have the first case:
that all of the $a,b,c,d \neq 0$,and so we have $i^4$ options to choose such a matrix.

second case: we have that $ \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & b \\
c & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$ or $ \begin{pmatrix} 
a & 0 \\
0 & d 
\end{pmatrix}$. so we have $i^2$  or $i^2$ on both,so $2i^2$ ways to choose a matrix.

third case : either the $a,b,c,d$ is zero and the rest nonzero.

I am not really sure. I would add the cases to get the final answer.
Can someone please help me? Any feedback would really help.
Thanks

Comment: Approaching directly like this would be fine.  Breaking into cases based on how many zeroes there are, there are $4$ choices for the location of a single zero, $1$ choice for the location of no zeroes, and $2$ choices for the location of two zeroes.  You can calculate the number of poossiblities for each choice in each case separately easily enough and add.

Comment: You're missing the situations where you have only one zero. There are four of those so $4i^3$.

Comment: So then the answer would be $i^4 + 4i^3 + 2i^2$? for such a matrix?

Comment: yes or $i^2(i+2)^2$

Comment: @Sentinel135$\ \ i^2(i+2)^2\ne i^4+4i^3+2i^2$

Comment: Nice catch bof! I missed the $-2i^2$ he's right it's $i^2((i+2)^2-2)$

Answer (score 5):

You may count the number of two tuples that can be formed from the elements of your set. clearly there are $(i+1)^2$ two tuples. Now the first entry should not be the vector $(0,0)$ so you have $(i+1)^2-1$ options for first row of marix. You have number of options for second row but then you have to subtract matrices of form $$ \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & b \\
0& d
\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$ \begin{pmatrix} 
a& 0\\
c & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$ (where $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are non zero)
 which are $2i^2$ in number.

so your answer should be $${[(i+1)^2-1]}^2-2i^2$$

Answer (score 3):

This is not the smartest solution, but I want to post it as an application of [inclusive-exclusive principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) (I personally love this principle).

The list/steps below may look lengthy, but it's actually very fast if you think within your head.

Plus, **it is very mechanical - just follow the steps, and thus less error-prone.**

We have $i+1$ integers to pick for each position.

**Start point**

Number of all matrix: ${(i+1)^4}$

**Subtract**

Number of matrix that has $0$ as its first row: ${(i+1)^2}$

Number of matrix that has $0$ as its second row: ${(i+1)^2}$

Number of matrix that has $0$ as is first column: ${(i+1)^2}$

Number of matrix that has $0$ as its second column: ${(i+1)^2}$

**Plus**

Number of matrix that has $0$ as its first **and** second row: $1$

Number of matrix that has $0$ as its first row **and** first column: $(i+1)$

Number of matrix that has $0$ as its first row **and** second column: $(i+1)$

Number of matrix that has $0$ as its second row **and** first column: $(i+1)$

Number of matrix that has $0$ as its second row **and** second column: $(i+1)$

Number of matrix that has $0$ as its first column **and** second column: $1$

**Subtract**

Number of matrix that has $0$ as its first row **and** second row **and** first column: $1$

Number of matrix that has $0$ as its first row **and** second row **and** second column: $1$

Number of matrix that has $0$ as its first row **and** first column **and** second column: $1$

Number of matrix that has $0$ as its second row **and** first column **and** second column: $1$

**Plus**

Number of matrix that has $0$ as its all columns and rows: $1$

**Thus**

The final result $=(i+1)^4-4(i+1)^2+(2+4(i+1))-4+1$
                 $$=i^2((i+2)^2-2)$$